# How to write a string into a ZipArchive stream

Tags: php

bzwrite() writes a string into the given bzip2 file stream. How to achieve to the same with ZipArchive()?

```
$str = "Hello";

$bz = bzopen("/tmp/foo.bz2", "w");
bzwrite($bz, $str);
bzclose($bz);
```

How to write $str to a ZipArchive stream?

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('/tmp/foo.bz2', ZipArchive::CREATE );

// ... how to write  $str to the zip archive ? ....

$zip->close();
```

Comment: Have you tried addFromString? https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php

Comment: I've seen that function too. But if I'm not mistaken, it expects a file name rather than a stream.

Comment: The filename is whatever you want to call the file within the archive, e.g. hello.txt, it will create the file and then write your string to it. What that means is that there is an extra level withing your archive, i.e. the string is not written directly into the archive but rather into a new file within it. Are you needing it to write directly to the archive like bzwrite?

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('/tmp/foo.bz2', ZipArchive::CREATE );
$zip->addFromString("foo", $str);
$zip->close();
```